# How do I change the x-axis datetime format to a mixture of time and date?

Tags: javascript, html, datetime, highcharts, heatmap

I have been trying to replicate an ADCP Graph using the Heatmap chart by Highcharts but I am finding difficulties in changing the x-axis format.

[Example of an ADCP Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWKMn.jpg)

How do i replicate the x-axis as shown in the example above?

I am also hoping for the format to be `date(dd/mm/yyyy), time(00:00), depth(m), velocity(m/s)` in the small popup that appears as you hover around the graph.

Here's a link to my code:
https://jsfiddle.net/6hzq3o12/6/

```
xAxis: {
  type: 'datetime',
  min: Date.UTC(2017, 0, 1),
  max: Date.UTC(2017, 11, 31, 23, 59, 59),
  labels: {
    align: 'left',
    x: 5,
    y: 14,
    format: '{value:%B}' // long month
  },
  showLastLabel: false,
  tickLength: 16
}
```

Comment: What you are asking does not make a lot of sense with your input data. You have data for a year, yet you want to show the hour of day like in the example ADCP graph. The tooltip is an easy fix, because that makes sense. See: https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/6hzq3o12/10/

Comment: Thanks for your response, ewolden. I've added into the csv portion but am failing to get it to work. https://jsfiddle.net/25cwrqen/30/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve expected effect you need to define your own `xAxis.labels.formatter` function, which recognizes labels on first, middle and last position, and then set its value format to `DD/MM/YY`. Otherwise (for all other labels) return the `HH:MM` value:

```
       xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            min: Date.UTC(2017, 0, 1),
            max: Date.UTC(2017, 11, 31, 23, 59, 59),
            labels: {

                formatter: function() {
                  var timestamp = this.value
                  var ticks = this.axis.tickPositions
                  var isMiddle = ticks.length % 2 && ticks.indexOf(this.value) === Math.floor(ticks.length / 2)
                  var labelFormat

                  labelFormat = this.isFirst || this.isLast || isMiddle ? '%d/%m/%y' : '%H:%M'
                  return Highcharts.dateFormat(labelFormat, timestamp)
                }
            },
            tickLength: 16
        }
```

However, in order to make it work correctly, you need to provide the chart with appropriate data (with hours), as @ewolden says in his comment below your main post.

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/25cwrqen/

Comment: Thanks for your response, Daniel. I've managed to get the time data into the project. Now I'm facing a new problem where the graph doesn't show up due to having one extra variable which is time. I'm pretty sure I'm providing the data wrongly. https://jsfiddle.net/25cwrqen/26/

Comment: It's because the time data should be part of date, not other column. You need to set every row like that:
`Date,Depth,Velocity 
"10/04/2014 10:16:36",1,0.7675003283
"10/04/2014 10:26:36",2,0.9115423085
`
Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/q4teysd9/

Comment: Alright, i've changed the dates and find that the data on the graph doesn't tele with the x-axis. The data is still going by date rather than date and time.  https://jsfiddle.net/q4teysd9/12/

Comment: Yes they do (you can see that by zooming it), but the chart need to show to big range of time, so the xAxis tick interval is a day now, that's why we can see the `00:00` values. You need to specify more precisely how your xAxis labels should behave, then i will help you to implement it.

Comment: The xAxis should be like "10/04/14, 04:00, 08:00, 12:00, 16:00, 20:00, 11/04/14, 04:00, 08:00.." where the data is plotted in minutes as seen in the ADCP Graph example above. Thank you and I'm so sorry for troubling you with this.

Comment: So, you need to show hour interval ticks between the days, but if an hour is equal to `00:00` then show the `DD/MM/YY` format of date, am I right?

Comment: So take a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/yz2apd4w/ . You can see, that If the tick value has time `00:00`, it's formatted to `DD/MM/YY`, otherwise it's just a time... Of course the first and last ticks are always formatted like in case with `00:00`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, Daniel. I've added in the actual data from the ADCP, made other changes and left your portion untouched and it looks perfect. Here's how it looks like now: https://jsfiddle.net/yz2apd4w/43/